# Successive differences in a 4d array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

If I had a typical array, I could find the difference between successive differences of the elements like this:

```
ex_sig = np.array([1, 3, -2, 0, 5])
succ_diff = ex_sig[1:] - ex_sig[:-1]
```

This gives me the difference between 3 and 1, -2 and 3, 0 and -2, and 5 and 0. However, I have a 4D array (fMRI data). My data (all_sig) has 4 dimensions (10 x 10 x 10 x 500), with the fourth dimension representing time. How can I compute successive differences in this case?

Comment: `succ_diff = ex_sig[...,1:] - ex_sig[...,:-1]`?

Comment: What does the ... stand for? It worked!

Comment: this is an ellipsis, it means that we take all values for all dimensions except the last one, for the last one we thus use `1:` and `:-1`.

Comment: Thank you! How should I close this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only slice the last dimension with:

```
succ_diff = ex_sig[..., 1:] - ex_sig[..., :-1]
```

The elipsis (`...`) will thus leave the other dimensions without any changes. We thus only slice the *last* dimension.